# Error with Twitter4J from Android with browser user authentication: No authentication challenges found

Tags: java, android, twitter, android-studio, twitter4j

I am trying to develop my own Android application using Android Studio 0.4.2 and the Twitter4J library. My idea is to use a WebView to load there the Twitter authentication page and get the AccessToken from there. I can get the oauth_token and oauth_verifier, but after that all the Twitter methods to get followers, post twits, whatever are not working.

This is my code:

```
public class TwitterLoginFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY = "***";
    private static String TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET = "***";
    private static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "http://www.hita.pro";

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Button btnTwitterLogin;
    private Button btnTwitterLogOut;
    private WebView wvTwitterLogin;

    private IDs iDs;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CONNECTION_INFO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        TwitterFactory.getSingleton().setOAuthConsumer(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_twitter_login, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstance);

        wvTwitterLogin = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.wvTwitterLogin);
        wvTwitterLogin.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN", true);
                editor.putString("OAUTH_TOKEN", url.substring(url.indexOf("oauth_token=") + 12, url.indexOf("&")));
                editor.putString("OAUTH_VERIFIER", url.substring(url.indexOf("oauth_verifier=") + 15));
                editor.commit();

                TwitterFactory.getSingleton().setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString("OAUTH_TOKEN", ""), sharedPreferences.getString("OAUTH_VERIFIER", "")));

                new GetTwitterFollowers().execute();

                return true;
            }
        });

        btnTwitterLogin = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnTwitterLogin);
        btnTwitterLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginToTwitter();
            }
        });

        btnTwitterLogOut = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnTwitterLogOut);
        btnTwitterLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                twitterLogOut();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loginToTwitter() {
        if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        wvTwitterLogin.loadUrl(TwitterFactory.getSingleton().getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL).getAuthenticationURL());

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                goToTwitterLogin();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_already_logged_twitter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            thread.start();
        } else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_already_logged_twitter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void goToTwitterLogin() {
        btnTwitterLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnTwitterLogOut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        wvTwitterLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN", false);
    }

    private void twitterLogOut() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN", false);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private class GetTwitterFollowers extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) {
            try {
                iDs = TwitterFactory.getSingleton().getFollowersIDs(-1);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            iDs.getIDs();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call to TwitterFactory.getSingleton().getFollowersIDs(-1) after the user has singed in, I'm getting this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

I'm desperated, I have spent one week trying to solve this problem but all the threads I have found in StackOverflow and other sites are not working. The system clock is OK, I have tried with ConfigurationBuilder and other solutions, but no luck. Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to work with instance not singleton from TwitterFactory?

```
Uri    uri      = Uri.parse(url);
String token    = uri.getQueryParameter("OAUTH_TOKEN");
String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("OAUTH_VERIFIER");

Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getInstance(
        new AccessToken(token,verifier);

twitter.getFollowers(-1);
```